# Throw an error during parsing if there are duplicate properties - System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I'm trying to migrate from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` and looking for a solution to throw an error if there are duplicate properties found during parsing Json.

Here's how it is done in Newtonsoft, but I couldn't find an alternative for System.Text.Json

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(
    item.ToLowerInvariant(), 
    new JsonLoadSettings() 
    {
        DuplicatePropertyNameHandling = DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Error 
    }
);
```

Comment: Why do you think Newtonsoft should have duplicate properties?

Comment: @Serge: OP never said it should. They said that System.Text.Json doesn't throw an exception when the input has duplicate properties and they want it to, like JSON.NET does with the setting shown. They're asking for a comparable setting.

Comment: This seems like you're migrating in the wrong direction

Comment: `JsonElement` and `JsonDocument` actually support duplicate properties, but `JsonObject` will throw an exception if, after parsing, you attempt to access any property.  See [JsonObject doesn't report duplicate keys until accessed #70604](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70604).  Sort of kludgy but maybe adequate?

Comment: @ReadyCent I'd argue with that since Microsoft claims it is much faster than Newtonsoft unless you have something to support your statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: @Serge: I don't disagree, but OP is saying that it's *not* doing that when it's what they want.

Comment: @Serge see this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/NrDLzO it has duplicate property named `attr`

Comment: @soccer7 all those yellow and red icons at the bottom of the article you posted - which at the time you posted it had not yet become a broken link but per microsoft policy will break at some point.

Comment: @soccer7 I am sorry, but it means that Text.Json is even worst then I thought

Comment: @dbc thanks for sharing link to github issue. It helps. So, the MS team has a open issue for this exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue link provided by @dbc provides part of the answer:

1. Read in the data as `JsonElement`
2. Run `EnumerateObject()`
3. Perform `GroupBy` and handle

```cs
var json = JsonDocument.Parse("{\"foo\":1, \"bar\":2, \"foo\":3}").RootElement;
var dupes = json.EnumerateObject()
                .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
                .Where  (g => g.Count() > 1)
                .Select (g => g.Key);

if (dupes.Any())
   throw ...
```